# WPF - InkCanvas touchscreen problem

Tags: wpf, touch, inkcanvas

I'm developing a touchscreen application, touchscreen overlay comes with its own SDK which disables all of the WPF default features. For example if I don't use this SDK i can easily draw on InkCanvas, program sees the overlay as a mouse input, but when I use this SDK it just doesn't recognize gestures, there are great features in SDK so I really want to use that, I can get the position of the touch point so how can I configure the InkCanvas to recognize this point and make me able draw based on this point.

BTW, I can draw with mouse when I use the SDK.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to not use the SDK if you can help it, and just use a multitouch driver. This simplifies things greatly. Once you have this driver you need to:

1. enable pen and touch in windows
2. respond to the TouchDown, TouchMove, and TouchUp events. the touches don't get translated into events the same way mouse clicks / drags do. Look at the "Raw Touch" section of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx).

if you dont have a driver, or you insist on using their SDK, you should still look into the Touch events I listed above, as these are most likely what you need.

Comment: Scott, I have the driver installed so I can use it SDK disabled, but I really need to use SDK it has great features that Windows do not have yet or hard to manage with codes, I tried many things with TouchDown, TouchMove, and TouchUp events but couldnt figure out.

Comment: the article has code that you can download and use in your project. Check out the code for the raw touch and see what he does.

Comment: I got it working with some minor changes , thanks a lot Scott, it was really what I am looking for